# How to track which item increases the memory in iOS using Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, memory-management

i have an iOS app there are 5 view controllers

in debug mode it starts with 30mb memory usage then when i use app and go to other view controllers it increases by 5 or sometimes more. never get down.

i use sqlite db and 
i use singleton class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoggedinUser : NSObject
{
   NSMutableArray *questionIDs;
}
+ (LoggedinUser *)sharedCenter;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *email;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *firmID;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *surname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userTypeID;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *firmName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *userID;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *dbFileName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *answerdbFileName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *lastOrderIndex;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *questionIDs;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *programID;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *merchantID;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIViewController *myQuestionView;
@end


#import "LoggedinUser.h"

@implementation LoggedinUser
@synthesize             userID,surname,name,userTypeID,email,firmID,firmName,dbFileName,answerdbFileName,lastOrderIndex,programID,questionIDs,merchantID,myQuestionView;

static LoggedinUser *sharedLoggedinUser = nil;    // static instance variable

+ (LoggedinUser *)sharedCenter {
    if (sharedLoggedinUser == nil) {
    sharedLoggedinUser = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
return sharedLoggedinUser;
}

- (id)init {
if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
    questionIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    myQuestionView=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedCenter];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    //[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

may be this could be my problem but i want to track which variable or which method increases memory when i walk through in my view controllers.

NOTE: it never increases if i am doing nothing on a view controller. it increases after i push to another view controllers

it is an iOS 7 app and use ARC

please just give me ideas to find what is the right way to find that how to track  variables and methods to find which one makes the problem

EDIT: @Mutawe Here is my Instruments screenshot i couldn't find object list in statistics? could you help please?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

- Open your Xcode project
- Choose the executable (if needed)
- Press `cmd+i` (Profile)
- Choose the 'Leaks' Instrument in Le Wizard (if needed)
- Press Return to begin profiling
- Exercise your app
- Press 'Stop' in Instruments
- Verify the 'Allocations' instrument is selected
- Click and Hold the Popup Button named 'Statistics'
- Select the Objects List item
- Locate the allocation you are interested in, among the records in the Objects List
- Select that allocation/object
- Click the 'detail arrow' to the right of the address in the table view cell of that allocation
- Now you see all events related to the allocation (allocation, free, reference count operations)
- Press `cmd+shift+e` for Extended Detail
- Go through the events in this list, and locate the imbalance you seek.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer i edited my question. i couldn't find statistics button and object list. i put a screenshot in my question. could you help?